# PB Order of execution

Tags: process-builder, order-of-execution

I have an object on which we have trigger, one of the batch class is also picking up those records and a process builder. Now when we create a record in that object, as per the order of execution, trigger will fire first on that record, then might be batch and then process builder.

Now the process builder which I have created has multiple conditions and the PB checks all the condition one by one and perform there respective actions.

Now in the last condition, I have used ISNEW() function but my concern is that once the trigger , batch and other conditions of the PB will execute on that record in that case the last ISNEW() condition will not work because the last modification date will change once the trigger perform his action and the record will no longer be a new record.

I want that last condition to execute on all new records. what is your suggestion?

Comment: Aside from the batch class, all of the stuff you mentioned in your question will be considered part of a "new record" transaction, so the final PB should still execute if all the conditions are met. If the PB depends on the execution of the batch class to set values, then you will need to redesign your process to meet those conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have one related questions, if we have 1 field where the values are keep on updating by 1, first from trigger, then wf and then PB and default value of the field is 1. what would be the outcome, would it be 4 or something else?

Comment: I haven't tested this scenario specifically, but I think the final answer should be 6. Default 1 -> trigger +1 -> workflow +1 -> trigger +1 -> process builder +1 -> trigger +1. The documentation isn't entirely clear on the matter, but it should almost certainly be higher than 4 thanks to trigger recursion. It could go even higher with recursive process builders, etc.